# How to include a library header after adding the linker in Eclipse

Tags: c++, eclipse, c++11, gcc, trie

I am trying to include a library from Github (https://github.com/dcjones/hat-trie).

The installation worked fine and I was able to add the library 
[to the linker in Eclipse](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B2vZi.png)

but the problem is that I don't know how to use it.

I have added it as a header

```
 #include <hat-trie.h>
```

but it's giving this error:

```
18:49:31 **** Incremental Build of configuration Debug for project test2 ****
make all 
Building file: ../src/test2.cpp
Invoking: GCC C++ Compiler
g++ -std=c++1y -std=c++11 -I/home/use1/boost_1_58_0 -O0 -g3 -Wall -c -fmessage-length=0 -MMD -MP -MF"src/test2.d" -MT"src/test2.d" -o "src/test2.o" "../src/test2.cpp"
**../src/test2.cpp:28:22: fatal error: hat-trie.h: No such file or directory
 #include <hat-trie.h>**
                      ^
compilation terminated.
make: *** [src/test2.o] Error 1

18:49:33 Build Finished (took 2s.831ms)
```

Any idea how can I fix this?

Comment: Looking at the command line, currently the compiler will only search its own standard libraries, the source folder of the file being compiled and the Boost folder. If hat-trie.h is not in one of these three places, the compiler won't be able to find it. Have you added the header location to Project->Properties->C/C++ General->Paths and Symbols->Includes (tab)?

Comment: I did but it is still the same problem

Comment: What does the g++ command line look like now and where on the drive is hat-trie.h?